# How to put multiple data in structure array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have different size of data. For example Dat1=12x1, Dat2=15x1, Dat3=19x1
My question is, how can I put the entire data in structure array. This is because easy for me to access the data.

Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go [structure array Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) to know how to implement it.

Basically what you need to do is

```
s = struct('Dat1',Dat1,'Dat2',Dat2, ...)
```

Just look in the section structure with multiple fields.